# Jupyter still showing removed print statements in pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

After commenting out print statements in an included file, the data from the old print statements are still shown even if I delete the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to exit the notebook file and open it again and re-run the cells. Also, you can clear all outputs as shown here :
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51862/Feature-Request-Add-clear-all-outputs-to-Jupyter-Notebook

by pressing double shift and then searching for "Clear Outputs", but for me that didn't prevent the old print statements from still being displayed.